# WCF service can't be recycled, because it cannot read keys from registry

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

My WCF service returns this error, when I start or recycle my App Pool.

It only happens during automatic deployment, just after I change website settings. When I recycle manually, it works fine.

```
[COMException (0x80040150): Could not read key from registry (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x80040150 (REGDB_E_READREGDB))]
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +607194
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +231
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +177
```